# 301 Redirect Classic ASP requests to ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp-classic

I've been given the task of figuring out how to handle 301 redirects for a Classic ASP site to a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application.  The domain name will remain the same.

Example of what I need to do:

```
Old Url:
http://www.example.com/index_cityname.asp

New Url (MVC):
http://www.example.com/cityname
```

The system will most likely be using IIS 8.x.  I'm developing on a Windows 8.1 machine and I've enabled ASP in the Features.  But when I enter an .asp extension in the browser, I get a 404.

I built a custom component that analyzes the incoming request and then checks a list and if it exists, it maps the new Response.RedirectPermanent(newPath, true) to the new path.  The only problem is, it never gets hit.  Somewhere earlier in the lifecycle the application sees that it's an .asp request, and exits.

Any ideas on how to make 301 redirects work from Classic ASP to ASP.NET MVC 5 using the same domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your web.config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

It belongs under `system.webServer` and `configuration`.

But beware performance and other issues using this setting. See http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect directly by using rules in web.config. I tried to write up your use case, but maybe you have to tweak the matching rule or target action to suit your needs.

Add this to your web.config:

```
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                    <rule name="redirect classic asp" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="index_(\w+)\.asp$" />
                        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I can't go into all details of web.config rewrite rules, but the best (easy) documentation I could find is here: [Learn.IIS Rewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

There is also a reference here: [Rewrite Module Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference)